# Adding columns to dataset in c#

Tags: c#, dataset

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
    static DataSet ds_input;
    static DataSet ds_output;


    ds_output.Tables.Add(new DataTable() );
    ds_output.Tables[0].Columns.Add("column_1", typeof(string));
    ds_output.Tables[0].Columns.Add("column_2", typeof(string));
    ds_output.Tables[0].Columns.Add("column_4", typeof(string));
    ds_output.Tables[0].Columns.Add("column_3", typeof(string));
```

Seems simple to me but somehow it is giving me following errors:

When initializing a new instance in `Add(new DataTable())`:

> Method must have a return type.

When adding columns to `ds_output.Tables[0]`:

> Invalid token '.' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Update #1:

I had written the above code in the beginning of the class as follows:

```
namespace Bulk_Verification
{ 
    public partial class Form1 : Form

    {   static DataSet ds_input;
        static DataSet ds_output;
            //ds_output.Tables.Add(new DataTable());
            ds_output.Tables[0].Columns.Add("column_1", typeof(string));
            ds_output.Tables[0].Columns.Add("column_2", typeof(string));
            ds_output.Tables[0].Columns.Add("column_4", typeof(string));
            ds_output.Tables[0].Columns.Add("column_3", typeof(string));
```

After suspecting that this might be the problem, i shifted these lines just before they are supposed to be used:

```
public static DataSet verify(DataSet ds_input)
        {
            ds_output.Tables.Add(new DataTable());
            ds_output.Tables[0].Columns.Add("column_1", typeof(string));
            ds_output.Tables[0].Columns.Add("column_2", typeof(string));
            ds_output.Tables[0].Columns.Add("column_4", typeof(string));
            ds_output.Tables[0].Columns.Add("column_3", typeof(string));
```

This is also the only method that returns a value (a customized dataset i am trying to create). Having the postion changed, now i get the following compiler error when i run the application using debugger, on `ds_output.Tables.Add(new DataTable());`:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: `static DataSet ds_input = new DataSet();
static DataSet ds_output = new DataSet();` Initialize the dataset like this, problem will be gone

Comment: Can you add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that you have the code as it is posted. So compiler complaints `Method must have a return type` and `Invalid token '.' in class, struct, or interface member declaration`.

You should create a `Method` and wrap your code in it, It can be instance method, constructor or static method or static constructor.

```
static DataSet ds_input = new DataSet();
static DataSet ds_output = new DataSet();

private static void InitializeMyDataSet()
{
    ds_output.Tables.Add(new DataTable() );
    ds_output.Tables[0].Columns.Add("column_1", typeof(string));
    ds_output.Tables[0].Columns.Add("column_2", typeof(string));
    ds_output.Tables[0].Columns.Add("column_4", typeof(string));
    ds_output.Tables[0].Columns.Add("column_3", typeof(string));
}
```

Then call `InitializeMyDataSet();` where you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, Check the declaration of dataset. I think you missed `new DataSet()` part

Answer (score 1):

**Add Column and Update that column of DataSet based on condition in Asp.net C#**

```
//Add new column in DataSet//
dsDetails.Tables[0].Columns.Add(new DataColumn ("Your_New_columnname")); 

//Iterate through DataSet//
foreach(DataRow dr in dsDetails.Tables[0].Rows) 
{
    //Store Specific column's value in a variable to check the condition//
    string name = dr.["Name"].ToString(); 
    for(int i = 0; i<= dsDetails.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        //Check if name value is null or empty then add new column in DataSet//
        if(name == "") 
        {
            //Update value in newly created column//
            dsDetails.Tables[0].Rows[d]["Your_New_columnname"] = "New_value Yes";
        }
        else
        {   
            //Update value in newly created column//
            dsDetails.Tables[0].Rows[d]["Your_New_columnname"] = "New_value No";
        }
    }
}
```

***dsDetails*** *is DataSet ID*